# Does "The Deluge" by Mauritius Lowe still exist? Where?

Tags: art

I have been reading "The Life of Samuel Johnson" by Boswell.  In the book it describes a painting "The Deluge" by [Mauritius Lowe](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Dictionary_of_National_Biography,_1885-1900/Lowe,_Mauritius) that was rejected by the Exhibition of the Royal Academy.  But Johnson used his influence to have the painting accepted.  I was hoping to see it if an image of it exists somewhere on the internet.  Anybody who could help me would be appreciated.

> In 1783 he sent a huge picture to the Academy, entitled ‘The Deluge—there were Giants on the earth in those Days.’ This was justly rejected, but at the earnest solicitation of Dr. Johnson it was ultimately admitted, though it was hung in an empty room by itself, and universally condemned.  *[DictionaryOfNationalBiography](https://In%201783%20he%20sent%20a%20huge%20picture%20to%20the%20Academy,%20entitled%20%E2%80%98The%20Deluge%E2%80%94there%20were%20Giants%20on%20the%20earth%20in%20those%20Days.%E2%80%99%20This%20was%20justly%20rejected,%20but%20at%20the%20earnest%20solicitation%20of%20Dr.%20Johnson%20it%20was%20ultimately%20admitted,%20though%20it%20was%20hung%20in%20an%20empty%20room%20by%20itself,%20and%20universally%20condemned.)*

The following may be useful if in fact Johnson had not seen the painting.

> We see lots of evidence of Johnson’s generosity, of his reputation as an honest broker, and of his great influence. When Mauritius Lowe’s painting “The Deluge” is rejected by the Royal Academy, Johnson, who has never seen the painting, writes to the Academy president (Johnson’s best friend) Joshua Reynolds as well as to James Barry, a professor at the Academy, and convinces them to have the painting included despite its rejection. *[mporcius.blogspot.com](https://mporcius.blogspot.com/2014/01/break-from-fiction-with-thomas-disch.html)*

Comment: I don't know about its current existence but the Gentleman's Magazine (Dec 1835) does mention that after being displayed (in a room by itself) at Somerset House, it had since been relocated. "[T]his painting is now at Sutton Place, near Guildford, Surrey, the property of John Webbe Weston, esq. where it occupies a conspicuous place at the end of the Hall." Sutton Place was recently home to Russian businessman Alisher Usmanov, perhaps the painting is still there?

Comment: @SteveBird - His assets were frozen due to Russo-Ukranian war sanctions in 2022, so I wouldn't be shocked if that painting got liquidated for usable western cash. (Or of course by cash-strapped owners of Sutton Place in any of the other preceding 187ish years)